# How to add the same line in file twice in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have the following code to setup PostgreSQL:

```
- name: mute install log1
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
    insertafter: '{{ item }}'
    line: 'exclude=postgresql*'
  with_items:
    - '^\[base\]'
    - '^\[updates\]'
```

However Ansible only adds one line depending on order in items list. How to add the same line in one file twice?

Comment: I strongly suggest using a `file` or `template`. Complicated `lineinfile` usage is an antipattern.

Comment: How would you use either of these in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it, avoiding multiple `lineinfile` calls, which is an antipattern.

### Modifying the existing file

Copy CentOS-Base.repo to your ansible `files` directory. Add the two `exclude` lines, and then publish that file:

```
$ cat CentOS-Base.repo
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
...
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
exclude=postgres*

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
...
```

and

```
- copy: src=CentOS-Base.repo dest=/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo owner=root group=root mode=0644
```

### Add a separate exclusions file

```
$ cat files/exclude-postgres.repo
[base]
exclude=postgresql*
[updates]
exclude=postgresql*
```

and

```
- copy: src=exclude-postgres.repo dest=/etc/yum.repos.d/exclude-postgres.repo owner=root group=root mode=0644
```

I thought there was a third way. I might add it later.

Comment: The first solution is kinda workaround for my problem, which depends on `CentOS-Base.repo` structure. The second one overrides the whole file. Why `lineinfile` is antipatern?

Comment: The second one overrides the while file by being placed *next* to it. That'd the advantage of conf.d systems. `lineinfile` is an antipattern because it doesn't allow very complicated logic and it treats the file on disk as an unknown entity. It's easy to switch to the `CentOS-Base.repo` and you gain a lot in consistency/repeatability.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I still don't understand the latter example. What do you mean by _next to_ it? The whole `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` with default configuration is replaced.

Comment: oops, I got the filename wrong. Editing to change it.

Comment: Ok, and the last question I promise. Can you describe shortly how does it exactly work? Does `system.d` loads `CentOS-Base.repo` firstly and then `exclude-postgres.repo`?

Comment: no worries! keep asking questions. the way a `conf.d` folder (you will see many in `/etc/`, also both apache and nginx) works is that it sucks up all files in that directory. It works really well for orchestration like Ansible, since you can write many small files instead of trying to manage one large file.